# Trying to add icon to my executable file, but keeps stated OSError [errono22]. Not sure what is going on

Tags: python, pyinstaller

There is nothing wrong with the .py file, since pyinstaller works perfectly without the added icon. Thus, I believe the problem may have something to do with the .ico icon file.

Anyone have any possible solutions to this problem? I am trying to add an icon using:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=mysnake.ico SnakeGameGUI.py
```

Here is the error recieved:

```
File "c:\users\BobJones\anaconda3\lib\site-packages/PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 118, in __init__
     file.seek(e.dwImageOffset, 0)
 OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see anything wrong in your `pyinstaller` usage so, as guessed, the issue is certainly the `ico` file used `mysnake.ico`.

Your `ico` file might be corrupted or incompatible with the way `pyinstaller` handle it.

**What `pyinstaller` does when managing the `ico` file**

`pyinstaller` open an icon file `.ico` in binary mode,

then read the header (6 bytes):

- idReserved (short/integer, 2 bytes)
- idType (short/integer, 2 bytes)
- idCount (short/integer, 2 bytes)

then read each image meta-data (16 bytes each):

- bWidth (signed char/integer, 1byte)
- bHeight (signed char/integer, 1byte)
- bColorCount (signed char/integer, 1byte)
- bReserved (signed char/integer, 1byte)
- wPlanes (short/integer, 2 bytes)
- wBitCount (short/integer, 2 bytes)
- dwBytesInRes (int/integer, 4 bytes)
- dwImageOffset (int/integer, 4 bytes)

then read the images themselves at location `dwImageOffset` and size `dwBytesInRes`.

In your case, `dwImageOffset` seem not to be an allowed value (a positive integer), hence the error.

**What you can do to solve your issue**

Icon `ico` file are pretty easy to make from the base image (jpeg, png, etc).
If you would decide to redo your `ico` file, I would recommend [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) for that task.

1. Open your base image (jpeg, png, etc), for instance `mylogo.png` in GIMP. (If you don't have it, you might try to open your `ico` file `mysnake.ico` in GIMP to see if you can extract it from there)
2. In GIMP, using `Image>Scale Image`, then `File>Export As...`, create several version of your image with different resolution:
   [image]

   - `mylogo_16x16.png`
   - `mylogo_32x32.png`
   - `mylogo_64x64.png`
   - `mylogo_128x128.png`
3. In GIMP, `File>Open`, then select your highest resolution image
4. In GIMP, `File>Open as Layers...`, then select the other images. Below is what you should get:
   [image]
5. In GIMP, `File>Export As...`, select the name of your desired `ico` file, e.g. `mylogo.ico`